# Stop Chrome from opening Google Maps app

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser, google-maps

My Google Maps app has got broken. I think I can use the web version of Google Maps. However, Chrome is redirecting me out from the browser to the app.

How to stop Google Chrome from redirecting me to the Google Maps app?

Answer (score 3):

In case any one else runs into this problem, you can stop this behavior by going to Settings -> Apps -> Google Maps and under More settings and permissions -> Open by default and disabling Open supported links to stop it from launching the app.  This works on both Android and Chromebooks to stop the Android app from launching any time a Google Map link comes up.

Answer (score 0):

A few options - open the Maps app info and disable it is the easiest. I also just noticed that with the Xposed module XPrivacyLua if I block Chrome from being able to get applications no links are ever opened in another app.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to disable Maps, I hope it will be fixed soon, I'm going to check if the Maps app is fixed from time to time.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev slightly confused - if your Maps app is 'broken' (you should clarify a bit more btw), why would disabling it affect you? Also try going to the Maps app info and clearing defaults, then Chrome should prompt you next time and you can just hit deny.